# Is there an easy way to do vacuum bake-out for UHV or other applications?

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum

Do you have issues trying to apply surface heat for vacuum bake-out?  Particularly UHV applications?  I see lots of suggestions on the web and also here, that inevitably talk about heat tape (make sure you know the distinction between flat heating cable which some people call heat tape, and a true, flexible heating tape element) and cables, and they usually end up insulated with wads of tinfoil.  End up looking like that turkey drumstick at Thanksgiving!!!

Seems a better solutions is cloth heating jackets, which can be controlled by a lab PID or modular system type PIDs where each cloth jacket has it's own PID.  You get complete coverage so there are no cold spots, and also avoid having to wrap with a tape and then an insulator.  Cloth heating jackets can be made custom or find a company that already makes component heaters.

Comment: I have seen one system that had a custom-designed clam shell that could be placed around the chamber. It had all the control bells and whistles. But, generally, it just doesn't matter that much - there is so much black art to getting all surfaces warm enough that it needs to be flexible.

Comment: I used to work on a UHV machine. The design and the cleanliness before/during mounting are important, but the back-out was never an issue. Make sure that you have enough temp sensors in your "turkey" and that you know which controller heats which part. The rest was manually and we never has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did just do a bing search for ultra high vacuum bake out.  I found an application note here at this link.
https://www.briskheat.com/applications/process-temperature-control-and-maintenance/vacuum-bake-out.html